# Wordpress JavaScript. Code works in script tag in footer, but not in a JS file

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm playing around with JavaScript at the moment in Wordpress since it is where we develop at work. (I'm an intern).

I have a list of JavaScript code that works in the script tag in the footer, but when i make a JS file and include that in the functions.php file, it does not run.

I have tested with an alert and a console.log and the file is running as it should, it is just the code that i have from before that does not run.

My code is this:

```
const nav = document.querySelector('#main');
let topOfNav = nav.offsetTop;

function fixNav() {
    if (window.scrollY >= topOfNav) {
        document.body.style.paddingTop = nav.offsetHeight + 'px';
        document.body.classList.add('fixed-nav');
    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove('fixed-nav');
        document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav);





const slider = document.querySelector('.items');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDown = true;
    slider.classList.add('active');
    startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
});

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    if (!isDown) return;  // stop the fn from running
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const walk = (x - startX) * 3;
    slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
});
```

And the code in functions.php is this:

```
`wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js')`;
```

The JS file is loading and running, it is just the code that only works in a script tag in footer, but not in a custom file.

Anyone that can guide me in the right direction. Not the answer, but just some hints so that i can try and learn for myself :)

Thanks alot.

Comment: Does the file get included in the bottom of the page? Or is it in the head?

Comment: It gets included in the head.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script` has five parameters - tag, url, dependencies, version and load in footer (bool). I'm guessing your code is being added to the head. Try this `wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '', TRUE );` - edit to add fifth parameter

Comment: So that means you event listeners get bound BEFORE the elements exist on the page so you need to use document ready or window onload to bind them. Or include the script in the footer, not the head.

Comment: Still gets included in head, and does not work.

Comment: @Rubylearner did you try with the updated edit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: The script is now added just before the closing body tag, but the code still does not work.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No. Not getting any errors at all.

Comment: Hmm...if you just put in a `console.log('hi');` does that return for you? If it does, then I would think that @epascarello is correct and the elements you are trying to affect are not loaded yet and you need to check to make sure the DOM is fully ready.

Comment: It did actually work after i got it in the footer. Just the cache in my browser that messed things up, so thanks for that :)

The problem was that it was not in the footer, so now I have learned that placing array(), '', true at the end makes it in the footer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<?php
 // wp_enqueue_script('handle', 'src', 'deps', 'ver', 'in_footer'); ?>
 wp_register_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
 wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
 ?>
```

call **wp_footer();** function in their footer just above the closing `</body>` tag.

For you

```
    <?php  
    if (function_exists('load_scripts')) {  
        function load_scripts() {  
           wp_register_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
           wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
        }  
    }  
    add_action('init', 'load_scripts');
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issue. If you look at the comments under the question, the JS file is loading in the footer, but the scripts are not functioning.